# Nginx url rewrite part of image name

Tags: nginx, rewrite

(disclaimer: I checked before asking this question but couldn't find an anwser)

In Nginx, I'm trying to rewrite this kind of image url so :

```
/img/products/us777.gif
```

becomes :

```
/img/products/big-777-instock.gif
```

The path stays the same, only the id 777 is "extracted" and served in a different image name.

I Tried without any success :

```
rewrite ^/img/products/big-(\d+)-instock.gif /img/products/us$1.gif;
```

Any idea on what to do to make it work ?

Thank you

Comment: Which of those URIs currently return the real image? Whereabouts in your configuration did to place the `rewrite` statement?

Comment: Hi, the url returning the original image is /img/products/us777.gif . AS of right now, all my rewrite rules are inside location / {

Comment: Without seeing your entire `server` block it's difficult to help. If you have a `location` for URIs ending with `.gif`, then the `rewrite` statement may not be seen.